# in Python Pandas, how to get one column, then skip a few columns, then get continuous columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I imported a csv file to a dataframe which I named as df.

```
df = pd.read_csv('csvfile.csv')
```

df has 8 columns, which have names A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H. then I need to get column B and columns E:H, and all the rows of these columns. 
I used 
`df1 = df.loc[:,"E":"H"]` to get columns E to H. But couldn't figure out how to get column B as well, still using `"E":"H"` in the code. The reason I want to keep `"E":"H"` is because the column names of E, F, G, H are very long, I tried to avoid typing all four names.
with thanks.

Comment: Did  you already try `iloc` instead of `loc`?

Comment: I didn't use df.iloc, because the I have multiple csv files, and they have different number of columns; some have 8, some have 10, etc. But the column names, which I wanted, are always the same, and the the columns names E to H are always together. I use df.loc so that I don't need to rewrite the code for different csv files.

Comment: `df.loc[:,list('BEFGH')]`. If the column names is not 'B' exactly, just make a list of all the column names and indexing with it.

Comment: thanks Ian. is there any way I can still use the style "E:H" in the code? because the column names are quite long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df.loc[:, list(df.columns[1]) + list(df.columns[4:])]
```

If you want to automatically find the columns, you can use

```
column_list = list(df.columns)
B_index = column_list.index('B')
E_index = column_list.index('E')
H_index = column_list.index('H')
df.loc[:, list(df.columns[B_index]) + list(df.columns[E_index:H_index])]
```

This is four lines, but the code is very readable.

Alternatively, if you know the exact names of the columns beforehand, it may be best to store those names in a list, and then use

```
column_names = [
    'B',
    'E',
    'F',
    'G',
    'H'
]
df.loc[:, column_names]
```

Comment: Thanks Jeremy. Is there a way that I can still use column names? As I mentioned,  I have multiple csv files, and they have different number of columns; But the column names, which I wanted, are always the same, and the the columns names E to H are always together.

Comment: I've added a way to do that, hopefully it helps! I also showed how you might explicitly write down the column names, if you know them beforehand, in a way that won't clutter your code.